# How can I convert unix timestamp into a CET & CEST timestamp without using ADD_DATE in FROM_UNIXTIME?

Tags: mysql, timezone

FROM_UNIXTIME returns GMT time. Due to the day light saving concept, I am forced to modify my query as I wrote below.

This is just an example of query, how I convert the unix time into CET time or CEST time.

```
SELECT order_id,
    date_created,
    DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created), INTERVAL 2 hour) AS "CEST Time",
    DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created), INTERVAL 1 hour) AS "CET Time"
FROM orders;
```

Is there any other way to do this effectively?

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()` returns the time in whatever your session timezone is, not necessarily GMT.

Comment: Anyway, use the `CONVERT_TZ()` function to convert a time from one timezone to another.

Comment: you are incorrect; from_unixtime returns the time in the timezone of your session.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e873707ea582c022a326563ff1c926c

Comment: is date_created an integer?  so much better to store times as datetime (in utc) and then select as `convert_tz(date_created, '+00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')`

Comment: @ysth Yes, I understand now that from_unixtime returns my timezone not necessarily GMT always. I used used convert_tz and it helped. Thank you.